How to Generate a Permutation Table for Cross Referencing Inputs in Google Sheets
I created a spreadsheet for myself and coworkers to help keep better track of keys for our master key system. The first sheet of this document lists the key names, the identifying stamp we've put on it as well as the cut numbers for the key. We use a drop down on the number in the quantity column to indicate which employees have that key. The second sheet is used to help figure the different cores that we pin, where they are located and we designate the key names that want to work in those cores columns E-P. The third sheet is the calculator that I made, you just type the ID for the core that you want to pin from column B of the 'Cores' sheet into the green box and array formulas read that and auto populate the key names that are typed the columns as authorized to work on that core. Other array formulas read the key names that populate and go to the first sheet and populate the cut number for each key into the table on the right.Example of Table Populated The table on the left then does simple math to calculate the pins that need to go into the cylinders of the core for those keys to work.Pins to be added to Core
What I would like to add to this is a kind of redundancy check to ensure that we don't accidentally make a key work where we don't want it to, especially when we are changing the number for an office that we are re-keying. I was trying to find a way for it to generate a permutation list of the numbers populated from B7 to H19 and then cross reference all 7 numbers in each row with the cut numbers from the 'Keys' sheet. If it finds an exact match on all 7 I'd like it to produce the names of the keys that it finds, from there I can read the names that it finds and reference them to the names that are authorized in the core that populated in the table on the right and see if there are any extra that aren't supposed to be there. I provided an example of this in the document. If you go to pin core 'OF 1 G' it gives access to everyone from Office 1 and the Managers from Office 2 through the Exterior Doors and the Conference Room. However there is one additional key that will work on this because it get all 7 cut numbers from 2 of the keys. 'Test Change 2AC' shares the first 4 cuts with 'Test Sub Master 2A' and the last 3 cuts with 'Test Change 1B' so this key will also turn the core even though we didn't mean it too.
I made a copy of the document, removed our key information and added some generic names and numbers and made this document public. This link will take you to the spreadsheet where you can see what I've built, see how it work and make edits to test stuff. Anyone with a link will be an editor but I will be monitoring changes made to the document and may remove that privilege if someone if someone does unnecessary changes that ruin the document. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18VUG0JLmdoVPOCZ4ixPBWcJ8DzxNMmU_0hBMcLIEwgY/edit?usp=sharing
In the sheet you will find a LAMBDA formula that was created by user JvdV in this thread created by user
mark fitzpatrick. Generate All Permutations in Excel using LAMBDA
This formula which is the alternative to the 2nd option that JvdV created is the closest one I've found so far to working. If you look in the fourth sheet labeled 'Extra' I copied the example that he had in the picture he provided to see if it would work but it doesn't seem to work right in Google Sheets.Duplicate of JvdV's Example from other Thread It generates the correct amount of rows but some reason it is not filtering properly and is creating duplicates. You'll also find the formula in cell B24 under the Cut Number table and I changed the cell range to be the first cut of the Grand Master key in B7 to the last cell in the table if populated H19. When it's trying to read that table it generates way more that wanted and not working as I was hoping. I'm guessing this has to do with 2 things, first that this formula was created for Excel and not Google Sheets and I don't know how to modify it to work there and secondly since the cells that are "blank" in the table aren't technically blank do to the IFERROR formulas in there.Small snippet of list formula generates

can you give us a TLDR
